# Joining Multiple Features to One Feature

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geoprocessing, attribute-joins

I have two layers - an index layer (polygon) and a town boundary layer (polygon).  The desired output is a FC with each town represented as only one feature and that FC's table having a field with values including all index layer features that intersect each town.

Is there one tool in ArcGIS that can accomplish this or am I looking at a multi-step process?

Comment: [Spatial Join](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000000q000000) might be for what you are looking.

Comment: Using Spatial Join (Join_one_to_one) I get one target feature (town boundary) and only one join feature (index layer) even though there are many intersecting join layers.  Using join_one_to_many) I get three (or more) target features duplicated over one another.  I don't want the features duplicated - I just want one feature with a field containing values of all the intersecting features.  Looks like a multi-step process.

Comment: I was able to get the desired output this way : in Spatial Join, under Field Map of Join Features, selected desired field to concatenate, right click, merge rule, join.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specify Merge Rule under Field Map of Join Features as 'Join'