# Spatial Joining multiple features (from one layer) to one feature os other layer on QGIS 3.4

Tags: qgis-3, attribute-table, attribute-joins, spatial-join

My objective is similar to the one especified on
[Joining Multiple Features to One Feature](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/67320/joining-multiple-features-to-one-feature)
The thing is that I'm on QGIS, and seems that tools are slightly different, so that confuses me on how to use the answers given to that question.

I'm working with a shapefile of urban lots (this is the shapefile I'm trying to copy the attributes to) and a shapefile with several coverage areas related to cultural patrimony elements in town. These coverage areas are the features overlapping inside the same layer.

Also tried the one-to-many spatial join mentioned by our friend, but the data is already very large (the lots attributes counts almost 2 million lines and 20 columns), so that is not much interesting to my needs, just like isn't much helpful the solutions with many processing steps.

Comment: You  mention both shapefiles and a database... do you have a database going?

Comment: My fault... bad english! I have no DB, I refer only to the lots shapefile size...